# Media Recorder in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios

someone can help me with this line of code?
recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'video/webm'});
when i use this variable in iOS, cath(err) answer me "RefenceError, cant find variable: mediaRecorder"
pleases can you helpe? if you need it this is the complete function

```
startBtn.addEventListener('click',function() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraint).then(function(stream) {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        mimeType: 'video/webm'
        });
        recorder.start();
    }).catch(function(err) {
        alert('impossible '+err);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the getUserMedia is only supported in safari browser

Any other browsers the getUserMedia is not supported in iOS devices

First check the availability of getUserMedia before you assign it to recorder

Good Luck